# Coming back from retirement

Tags: football, transfer

Can a football player retire if he is not getting a transfer away from his current club and then come back from retirement to join a new club?

Can such methods will earn him a move or will he has to play for the same club again?

Comment: If the contract was abandoned, which it most likely would be, **yes**.

Answer (score 1):

If the contract is still active there are two ways:

1. The player ask for rescission and he will take back "his property". In this case is is free to choose another team and the new team should not pay for the player (see player Iker Casillas moving to Porto from Real Madrid in summer '15)
2. The team sacks the player and the player start to play to another team. In this case the new team has probably pay money to old team, but it depends on the courts where the teams talk about the questions)

If the contract in ending the player is free to sign to another team just at the end of the contract to another team (see free player Antonio Cassano moving to Sampdoria in summer '15). Normally the old team take no money from the new team, but if the player is very young the new team has to pay a contribution for the growth of the young player (see young Paul Pogba moving from Manchester UTD to Juventus in summer '12)

Answer (score 1):

You obviously cannot unilaterally announce to terminate the contract. Imagine telling your boss one day that you're "retiring" from the business only to emerge one week later at a competitor. Does it make any sense? The common usage of "retirement" in football usually comes after the player's contract has ended.